# Android Trouble with Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

In my application i am allowing user to add upto 5 `EditText` views by clicking "Add More Contacts". But when a `EditText` view appears the layout falls vertically. So i want to place a `ScrollView` for the `EditText` Views only not for the `Button`. I am trying but failing everytime. Can someone please help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="237dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="236dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/et_display" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bpickperson"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="169dp"
    android:text="@string/b_pick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/balert"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/b_alert" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/baddmorecontacts"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/b_addmorecontacts" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_facebook"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/b_facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_twitter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_twitter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show some code where you programatically add the `EditTexts`, and by `failing everytime` what exactly is the actual result?

Comment: there is no scroll view used in your .xml here.

Comment: @bhanu: I don't see any `ScrollView`. you need to add a child scrollview to your LinearLayout.

Comment: what i mean to say , that i am trying to put scroll view but i am not able to get the desirable result that i want. What i am trying to do is the Edit Text views will have the scroll view and buttons remains steady where are already are.

Comment: @AndyRes shall i show you the whole code ??

Comment: @AdilSoomro i  have added a child ScrollView to the linearlayout. But my buttons are not visible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/et_display" >
        </EditText>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bpickperson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_pick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/balert"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_alert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/baddmorecontacts"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_addmorecontacts" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_facebook"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b_facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_twitter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b_twitter" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

A ScrollView can only contain ONE child view. Right now it contains an EditText, so it can't contain any more child views. You have to put your EditTexts into another layout, lets say a LinearLayout and put that LinearLayout into the ScrollView. You then add your EditTexts to the LinearLayout and not to the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id ="@+id/editlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip" 
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:hint="et_display" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bpickperson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="b_pick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/balert"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="b_alert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/baddmorecontacts"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="b_addmorecontacts" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_facebook"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="b_facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_twitter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="b_twitter" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```